# Is it possible to copy entire HR schema in our schema in Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am unable to unlock HR schema no matter what. Now I am thinking that is it possible to copy all tables from HR into different schema some how? I need to access tables from HR schema for testing purposes.

Comment: It sounds like you just need various table privileges associated with the HR schema.  Once you "unlock" the privileges you need (e.g. `select`, `update`, `insert`, ...), what will you do with them?  Perhaps you do not need to copy the schema to accomplish your task.

Comment: When you say "I am unable to unlock HR schema no matter what" what does that mean? What have you tried? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

You can use datapump to export the schema and import it into another schema.  However if you don't have access to "unlock" HR, you may not have privileges to do this.  Your DBA can create the test schema or give you permissions to HR.  Remapping the tablespace is optional.

```
sql> create or replace directory EXPDIR as 'c:\data';
sql> grant read, write on directory EXPDIR to user;

c:\> expdp user/psw schemas=HR directory=EXPDIR dumpfile=HR.dmp  logfile=expdpHR.log

c:\>impdp user/psw schemas=HR remap_schema=HR:HRTST remap_tablespace=HRTS:HRTSTTS directory=EXPDIR dumpfile=HR.dmp logfile=impdpHRTST.log
```